Playwright with chai, can't check element visibility
I'm relatively new with Playwright, and despite PW already have an expect function library, I am trying chai to check if can be useful to my tests and their readability.
So I did (since I'm using typescript)
npm install -D @types/chai
to install it, and I added on top
import { expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { expect as expectChai } from 'chai';

to be able to use them both.
Btw I want to use chai only in the near future, so I'm trying to change all the expects, and I am currently having trouble with this one (I simplified the code for readability):
import { expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { expect as expectChai } from 'chai';

export class PortalPage extends ModelPage {
    private init: string = 'span.info';
    private loader: string = '#loader-mobile';

    constructor(page: Page) {
        super(page);
    }

    async init(): Promise<void> {
        await this.page.waitForSelector(this.init);
    }

    private async waitForLoader() {
        if (this.page.locator(this.loader)) {
            // playwright expect: ok
            expect(this.page.locator(this.loader)).not.toBeVisible;
            // chai expect: Property 'visible' does not exist on type 'Assertion'
            expectChai(this.page.locator(this.loader)).not.to.be.visible;
        }
    }
}

While the expect with playwright works perfectly, the chai one gives me this error (.visible is underlined in red and error appears hovering the mouse on it):
Property 'visible' does not exist on type 'Assertion'
I've also tried with expectChai(this.page.locator(this.loader)).should('not.be.visible') but no luck: no red lines, but when running the test, error says:
Error: Invalid Chai property: should.
So clearly is there something that is not going like it should.
Is there something I'm missing?
Is it possible that chai doesn't have any assertion for checking elements visibility (or properties in general)?
If so, is there any chai plugin I can use for?

Please don´t use waitForSelector -> ref. By using PW ´s locators you have a powerful tool. The locators would be init = page.locator('span.info') and loader = page.locator('#loader-mobile') inside the conscrutor. The expectation will be await expect(this.init).not.toBeVisible() -> ref. About your chai assertion I don´t have experience. sry. For more help please share a minimum example which can reproduce your issue (html, DOM).

Don't use chai with Playwright. Playwright already has all the assertions you'll need. Chai assertions aren't web-first, meaning they aren't event-driven and don't auto-wait for the predicate to be true as Playwright matchers do.
You should be using web-first assertions 98% of the time, so even if the Chai assertions worked, this would be a major antipattern.
Your Playwright assertion is also incorrect:
expect(this.page.locator(this.loader)).not.toBeVisible;

is a bug. Unlike Chai, you need to call the matcher function and await the promise, otherwise this is a no-op (and a race condition without await):
await expect(this.page.locator(this.loader)).not.toBeVisible();

Also, conditions are generally not necessary in Playwright, so remove
if (this.page.locator(this.loader)) {

Locator actions generally throw, not return falsey, and this locator doesn't have an action or an await, so it's always true.
Beyond that, there won't be any readability increase in using Chai. Playwright is similar to Jest, which is far more popular than Chai nowadays. Both libraries' assertions are state of the art. By using a different library than virtually 100% of other Playwright tests, you'll have an unnecessarily rough time finding help or hiring other engineers to quickly get up to speed on your codebase. It'd be a major burden/friction point in adopting the library.
There are many other issues in this code, like using CSS selectors which aren't user-facing, and using discouraged functions like waitForSelector (use locators instead, and move them to the POM constructor).
I suggest abandoning Chai and working through some Playwright tutorials so you will understand how to use the library as it's intended to be used.

Sorry, that toBeVisible is just a typo in my code, thanks for noticing that.
I am also switching the waitForSelector functions to waitFor, I have clearly missed this one :)
I am actually working in a company and I was requested to add Chai in the code, but now I have a good reason to not do it!
But many thanks for the tip about Chai: I really did not have idea that it was not web-first, nor I had idea of what it meant. I learned something new today :)

I'd push back. You can tell them the #3 Playwright answerer on Stack Overflow said not to do it, just use plain Playwright without other assertion libraries and follow all Playwright best practices.
